# CPU usage gets higher as more WebRTC peers are added?

Tags: node.js, electron, webrtc, peerjs

I'm streaming video/audio from a server with an electron app to get the desktop. When one user is connected CPU usage on both cores is 30-50%. As more users join the usage gets higher, when there were ~6 users it was a constant 100% on both cores and video quality becomes laggy and poor.

It's like it's encoding the video for each user that joins? How can I make it encode once and send that stream to everyone? That's my only guess as to why cpu usage would get so much higher anyway, maybe I'm wrong about why. Thank you for any help you can give! I'm open to other ways of doing this as well, as only the server needs to send video out.

Getting the video and audio:

```
function getAudio(audioID){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia( { video: false, audio: {deviceId: {exact: audioID},
        autoGainControl: false, channelCount: 2, echoCancellation: false, noiseSuppression: false, sampleRate: 44100, sampleSize: 16 } } )
        .then(function(stream) {
            console.log("audio got??");
            var audio = stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
            mediaStream.addTrack(audio);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        });
}

desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['screen'] })
.then(async sources => {
    console.log(sources);
    let constraints2 = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            maxWidth: 1280,
            maxHeight: 720
            }
        }
    }

    let constraints3 = {
        frameRate: {max: 24}
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints2)
    .then(function(stream){
        mediaStream = stream;
        let track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        track.applyConstraints(constraints3);
        setTimeout(function(){
                getAudio(audioID, 0);
            }, 2000);
    })
    .catch(console.error);

})
.catch(console.error);
```

Calling the peers that join:

```
peer = new Peer(myPeerID, {host: 'selfhostedpeerjs.com', port: 9000, path: '/', key: 'peerjs', config: {'iceServers': [{ url: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302' },
    {url:'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302'},
    {url:'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302'},
    {url:'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302'},
    {url:'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302'} 
    ]}
});

peer.on('open', function(id){
    console.log("My peer id is: " + id);
});

peer.on('connection', function(conn)
{
    conn.on('open', function(){
    console.log("connection opened");

    var id = conn.peer;
    //conn.send('Hello!');
    console.log("Trying to call now");
    var call = peer.call(id, mediaStream);
    call.on('error', function(err){
        console.log('calling error');
        console.log(err);
    })
});
```

Comment: " How can I make it encode once and send that stream to everyone" that's what MCU does. It mixes streams from many endpoints and sends them out as a single manageable stream to everyone so that endpoints don't end up putting in too much CPU in managing all streams separately. I assume u are currently using full Mesh. You can switch to using MCU or SFU setups for meetings above 20 participants. Ps: hope the answer is not too late and can help others too.